# Как сравнить элементы находящиеся в одной строке в двумерного массива и вывести их на экран?

Tags: c++

написала самостоятельно код но он не работает. подскажите где ошиблась

```
void eq()
{
  for ( i = 1; i < n; ++i)
  {
    for ( j=1; j<m-1; ++j)
    {
      if(mas[i][j]=mas[i][j+1])
  {
    cout<<"Odinakovye elementy est"<< j <<endl; 
        for ( j=0; j<m; ++j)    
    cout<<mas[i][j]<<" ";
  }   
  else
    cout<<"Error"<<endl;
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: @машенька, что значит "не работает"?

Возможные варианты:

1. не компилируется;

2. запускается и завершается с "системной" ошибкой;

3. выводит не то, что Вы ожидаете.

В любом случае, Вы предлагаете нам самим догадаться о значениях `n`, `m` и `mas[][]`?

--

Где-то в справке по форуму написано, как правильно оформлять вопросы.

Comment: @машенька, если это C/C++, то индексирование в массивах начинается с нуля! Это касается первых двух циклов, а третий, как ни странно, правильный. И во втором учли дальнейшее сравнение с j+1 -м элементом.

В C/C++ есть СРАВНЕНИЕ, а есть ПРИСВАИВАНИЕ (присвоение). На предупреждения транслятора стоит обращать внимание.

Вам надо найти соседние одинаковые элементы (расположенные друг за другом в одной строке), как следует из кода, или как-то иначе?

А вывести вам надо только совпадающие элементы, или их индексы, или строки целиком (как в вашем коде)?

Comment: P.S. "Извини, в ответах я ограничен. Правильно задавай вопросы." ("Я - робот")

Comment: @paulgri я хочу чтобы он выводил строки с совпадающими элементами и по возможности сами элементы.

Comment: @машенька, если вы вывели строку как значения ее элементов (как в вашем коде), то сами элементы вы уже вывели. Надо определить, что значит вывести строку и элемент: значение, номер или и то, и другое.

Заметьте, если задача "вывести на экран строки, имеющие одинаковые элементы", то после первого совпадения искать новые в той же строке уже нет смысла и можно прервать этот цикл.

И еще раз насчет совпадения: нужны одинаковые и ПОДРЯД расположенные элементы или совпадающие значения во всей строке, например 2-й и 7-й? Во втором случае алгоритм поиска совпадений будет другим.

Comment: @paulgri спасибо большое, разобралась.

Answer (score 0):

Может быть это то что вы имели ввиду:

```
array< array <int,4>,4> mas;
for(auto& i:mas){
    for_each(i.begin(),i.end(),[](int& j){return j = rand()%10+1;});
}
cout<<"basic matrix"<<endl;
print(mas);

cout<<endl;

set<int> mg1;
set<array<int,4>> mg2;
for(size_t i = 0; i < mas.size(); ++i){
    for(size_t j = 0; j < mas[i].size(); ++j){
        for(size_t k = mas[i].size()-1; k > j; --k){
            if(mas[i][j] == mas[i][k]){
                mg1.insert(mas[i][j]);
                mg2.insert(mas[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}

cout<<"rows:"<<endl;
for(auto it = mg2.cbegin(); it != mg2.cend(); ++it){
    for(auto& i: *it){
        cout<<i<<' ';
    }
    cout<<endl;
}

cout<<endl;
cout<<"same numbers:"<<endl;
for(auto it = mg1.cbegin(); it != mg1.cend(); ++it){
    cout<<*it<<' ';
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Замените знак равенства на присвоение

```
if(mas[i][j] = mas[i][j+1])
```

Comment: Насколько я вижу в вопросе знак присвоения.

Comment: Наоборот же!!!!